# jQuery $.post Syntax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, phpstorm

I am using phpStorm to edit a file. This code breaks the page:

```
$("#delete_all_button").click(function(){
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'pickup_list_all' );
    var selectedRows = oTT.fnGetSelectedData();

    first = selectedRows[0][selectedRows.length-1];
    $.post("delete.php", {'claimID': first}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Specifically the colon inbetween claimID and first. When I hover overtop a red squiggly underneath the colon, the editor tells me "} expected". When I try and load the page, I get no error in the console and the page is just white.

Another important thing to note is that when I copy previously working post code from another file which has no errors in the code to this file, the errors appear.

What could be the problem? Libraries?

I have imported jquery with the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question, perhaps, but did you check the console to see if the data was actually logged? `console.log` doesn't print anything to the page itself, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The syntax is correct, are you sure this code is what's causing errors?  I ran it in my console and didn't get a syntax error.

Comment: I understand what is giving me the error now. These are not .html files. They are .tpl files which are template parsers written in php. They behave differently when you have a line such as {xxxx:xxxx} so it is indeed a syntax error, but now I must figure out how to make smarty not mess it up and view it as such hahahah.

Comment: Since this JavaScript is located in Smarty template, have you tried selecting **Settings | PHP | Smarty | Use Smarty 3 whitespaces policy** check box? It's all about how PhpStorm interprets the Smarty variables/instructions. Otherwise you have to surround your JS code with `{literal}...{/literal}` tag to have JS code interpreted properly by PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data parameter of [jquery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) expects "A map or string that is sent to the server with the request."  You could try changing the second parameter to `JSON.stringify({'claimID': first})` or wrap it in brackets to make it an array `[{'claimID': first}]`

Comment: Hmmmm Eric. Very clever. If you read my response to Rocket you'll see my true problem. Your suggestion has given me an idea. Since Smarty takes anything of the form {xxxx:xxxx} and uses it differently than jQuery intends, I may try something like this:

var name = "'claimID':";
        first = selectedRows[0][selectedRows.length-1];
        $.post("delete.php", name+first, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

Answer (score 0):

The standard is that you do not use quotation for the property name. Some old browser could crash because it.

```
$("#delete_all_button").click(function(){
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'pickup_list_all' );
    var selectedRows = oTT.fnGetSelectedData();

    first = selectedRows[0][selectedRows.length-1];
    $.post("delete.php", {claimID: first}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: The colon wasn't in the property name. I think the issue was that he put the key name as a string, so your code is correct anyway.

Comment: Do not use colon? Do you mean do not use quotation? (that was the change you made). And I am using a current version of chrome. Tried your code and still the exact same error. Thank you though.

Comment: Sorry, I mean do not use quotation.